# How to check if BackStack is null

Tags: java, android

I want to check if BackStack is null.
I have something like this:

```
 List<Fragment> l2 = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
        if(l2 == null){
            todo
        }
```

but `getFragments` need API 26, my is 16

How to solve it ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

use this line

```
 if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0)
   {
       ---  your code here
   }
```

Comment: As I can understand, getSupportFragmentManager() will return List, so why we need to check it's count?? rather then checking nullity. I m just asking for curiosity.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager doesnot returns the list.. it just returns FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this activity.
getBackStackEntryCount() returns the number of fragments in the backstack..

Comment: Thank for the such detailed explanation @Zainab, that is correct getSupportFargmentManager never return list, but when we are using getBackStackEntryCount(), then it will return size of  mBackStack ArrayList, so I think going with List along with Object nullity will be a good, I follow below code snap for FragmentManager  
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.0mBackStack

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether Android SDK support complete JDK 8 feature or not but, best way to check nullity is with **Objects** class method **isNull** which is under util package.

This way you can check nullity :

```
if(!Objects.isNull(obj)){
// business logic
}
```

I just observe other answer here and as per that I have one suggestion like, along with List level nullity check (I guess method you are using return List data) we should also check object level nullity. And with Java 8 we can do it very smoothly with **Stream api** , below I m sharing example code for it:

```
List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(ls.stream().allMatch(x-> x==null)){
            // Todo 
            }
```

Hope this will help!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code

```
int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (backStackEntryCount == 0) {
            goBack();   // write your code to switch between fragments.
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use fragment stack while pushing fragments inside it.

```
Stack<Fragment> fragmentStack
```

and check

```
if(fragmentStack.size == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getBackStackEntryCount() to get count. If it is zero, means nothing in backstack.

like `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()`

---

Or like

```
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
    // Current fragment is last one in stack
}
```

---

Note: [FragmentManager class was deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) in API level P.
Use the Support Library FragmentManager for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle.

So if you are developing new application or can update existing classes, use [getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()). For this purpose you need to use [android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: but I need to check it is null or not, I got nullpointer sometimes

Comment: @goodweather as per doc 'This will not include any fragments only in the back stack, or fragments that are detached or removed.' So it may null